# Wix: CustomAction rollback action is not executed

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am writing rollback action for my feature, and that is created as custom action, there are other  multiple CAs and rollback actions. I want to my feature executed in last execution sequence of all rollback action.
I could have specified my rollback action execute after lastmost rollback CA.
but my feature CA and rollback are part of separate merge module and its consumed  as mergemodule

```
    <CustomAction Id='CustomActionId.InstallMyFeature'  Return="ignore"  BinaryKey='msiutils' DllEntry='CAInstallmfeature' Execute="immediate"/>
    <CustomAction Id='CustomActionId.UninstallMysvfeature'  Return="ignore"  BinaryKey='msiutils' DllEntry='CAUnInstallmfeature' Execute="rollback"  Impersonate="no"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='CustomActionId.InstallMyFeature'  Before='InstallFiles'>NOT Installed</Custom>
        <Custom Action='CustomActionId.UnInstallMyFeature' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But this rollback action is not executed when installation failure happened.
Any help really appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to schedule your rollback action before the action it serves as a rollback for, so in your example:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='CustomActionId.InstallMyFeature'  Before='InstallFiles'>NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action='CustomActionId.UnInstallMyFeature' Before='CustomActionId.InstallMyFeature'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It would also be nice if both actions had the same condition.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I did not get how could be rollback action 'CustomActionId.UnInstallMyFeature' sequence before 'CustomActionId.InstallMyFeature'.  Would not rollback  always after CA?

Comment: Windows installer is basically writing two scripts for deferred execution - install and rollback script. When install fails at some point, it starts executing the rollback script, in reverse direction, from the point of failure. So, if you schedule rollback action after the actual action - it has no chance to execute since it's farther in the rollback script than the original action was in install script.